# External stylesheets and js files not linking in server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, server

I have a website developed in `bootstrap` and `laravel 5.0` I am trying to upload it to the `000webhost.com` for testing purpose before going live on my domain. I have uploaded it on the server but the `stylesheet` and `js` files are not linking properly.

I have this on my actual file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/animate.css')}}">
<!--animate.js-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/coreStyleSheet.css')}}">
<!--Font Awesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" {{asset('icon/fontAwesome/css/font-awesome.css')}}">
<!--customeJS-->
<script src="{{asset('js/coreHomePage.js')}}"></script>
<!--fullPage.js-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('fullPage/jquery.fullpage.css')}}">
```

I have used `{{asset('source')}}`

but when in 000webhost nothing is working properly when I opened the source file it is like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://devfairtex.000webhostapp.com/server.php/css/animate.css">
<!--animate.js-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://devfairtex.000webhostapp.com/server.php/css/coreStyleSheet.css">
<!--Font Awesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://devfairtex.000webhostapp.com/server.php/icon/fontAwesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<!--customeJS-->
<script src="https://devfairtex.000webhostapp.com/server.php/js/coreHomePage.js"></script>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with css or javascript tags. Please don't spam tags and only use what is relevant to the specific code problem

Comment: sorry about the mate @charlietfl

Comment: What does your .htaccess file look like!

Comment: I have edited and added the .htaccess file. Please take a look @DomDaFonte

Comment: Thanks. And what does your web root folder structure look like? What's odd is your URL is showing the server.php which would indicate something odd with how you copied your Laravel app into your web server.

Comment: this is laravel project where the starting point is `server.php` then the server.php redirects to `index.php`

Comment: Send over your apache or nginx configuration that shows which folder you are pointing 000webhost.com to as its document root.

Comment: I need to see your configuration that points your site to the url mentioned.  As an example, here is my vhost setup for a particular url on my localhost:

        <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
        DocumentRoot "C:/wamp2/www/landing/public"
        ServerName demo.landing
        <Directory "C:/wamp2/www/landing/public">
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

Comment: I don't understand. Where can I find that in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**hey remove this from your .htaccess file. :)**